# Using dplyr mutuate (or other package) to create new column based on count of specific values in each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing several forms of data, such as:

```
<dbl> <chr> <dttm> <chr> <chr> 
0001 cccc Feb-01-18 bbbb 1ab76
0002 bbbb Apr-02-20 cccc 7we54
...
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new column "f" that returns a count of the number of specific character values (e.g., "cccc" OR "bbbb") within each row. I've tried using a combination of the dplyr merge function and rowSums but have not had any luck despite trying several variations.

```
df %>% mutate(new = rowSums(. == "cccc"))
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would  be to specify the `|`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(f = rowSums(. == "cccc"| .== "bbbb"))
```

---

Also, this can be  made  more specific by checking only columns that are `character`  class

```
df %>%
      select_if(is.character) %>%
      transmute(f = rowSums(. == "cccc"  | .  == "bbbb"))%>%
      bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: Sorry , I didn't see the comment

Comment: (My fault, I'm having some formatting issues.) Thanks for the help. I don't know why this shouldn't work but I'm getting a seemingly unrelated error back:

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots):  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.`

Any ideas?

Comment: @aakzeman  Can you update with the `dput` of the  small example to understand the structure

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by `dput`? I updated the small sample to reflect the data formats if that's helpful?

Comment: @aakzeman  If you type `dput(df)` (assuming the dataset identifier is `df`, you will  get a structure of the dataset.  For testing, it is better to have only few rows, so you can do `dput(head(df))`

Comment: sorry this is evolving away from the initial problem. I used `str(head(df))` which returned `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  46 variables:
 $ ID   : num  9.06e+08 9.06e+08 9.06e+08 9.06e+08 9.06e+08 ...
 $ Start_Date : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-06" "2014-12-10" "2014-12-06" "2014-11-17" ...
 $ Status : chr  "YES" "NO" "YES" "YES" ...
 $ End_Date   : POSIXct, format: "2017-08-02" "2015-05-09" "2016-12-10" "2015-12-12" ...`

Comment: @aakzeman  I meant `dput(df)`.  Can  you try the updated version  of my solution

Comment: Thanks again for continued help. The solution worked but returned an entire column of `NA`'s. I confirmed the column data are characters, and the values I'm trying to count exist, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: @aakzeman  Could be that you have `NA` elements, try the `na.rm = TRUE` in `rowSums` i.e. `rowSums(. == "cccc"  | .  == "bbbb", na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked exactly as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("c","b"), d = c("c", "c"), e = c(1,2), stringsAsFactors = F)
pattern <- "c"
df["count"] <- rowSums(apply(df, 2, function(x, s = pattern) x %in% s))
```